# My dogbone bamboo sample's grips keep breaking

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I used an Instron 5581 Tensile Testing machine to test the tension of several bamboo samples that were sanded into dogbone shapes. They kept breaking at the grips and I am not sure why?[image]

Comment: A picture would help : change of diameter? Sharp change ie a stress riser?

Comment: Just added a picture for you.

Comment: I suspect in the way you attach some side to side force is created.

Comment: If that machine is anything like the one I used at Uni - the clamps are located with pins to reduce the chance of side force - but you do have to get things in line...

Comment: I am going to use different grips next time and also make sure that the samples are aligned near perfect.

Comment: As I mentioned in the other post, the grips are marginal for that thickness. You need a shorter length of reduced section and some free length between the grips and the test section. I wouldn't use sanding. I would use a very keen edge tool to finish the sample after routing it to shape.  You basically have a notch test sample, but that isn't what you want. It takes a lot of length for woods to transfer shear across fiber bundles. The taper angle at the transition should be very small, like 5 degrees small, not a 90 degree notch with a little radius.

Answer (score 1):

Have the necked section slightly shorter and make sure the radiusing is smooth...

But, I would suggest that you should consider either natural defects (that may not be visible) causing failure or you are just hitting the tensile strength - did they break at around the same value?

How many have you tested so far - if it is only those two then you need to do more to confirm the cause.

You should do a test on a piece that does not have any reduction in csa but perhaps just a bit thinner to see as well.

Comment: Thank you! I will try that or create separate grips for the next samples.

I had a total of 7 samples I tested. 
They all broke under 10nK of Load

A few of my samples that were about 1-2mm thick broke near the center, so thinner might be better.